# Bash isn't recognizing gulp command

Tags: bash, gulp

`sudo npm install -g gulp` on Ubuntu isn't allowing me to access the gulp command.

When cd into my project that has a gulpfile, and run the `gulp` command, nothing happens.

`which gulp` = `/usr/bin/gulp`

Anyone know what the issue could be?

EDIT :

I have installed gulp and followed the documentation yet nothing is working.

Comment: Please detail what "nothing happens" means: No output at all? Or an error message? What is the exit code?

Comment: @mklement0 by "nothing" happening i mean I am getting no output or an error message. just nothing happens.

Comment: I see; and the exit code is (`echo $?`)? Does my answer provide any pointers?

Answer (score 3):

The problem lied in the paths.

Because some dependencies will use the `node` command instead of the `nodejs` command, there has to a link to the paths.

`sudo ln /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node` solved this for me.